# image upload validation in codeigniter custom validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue as follows
I have set a rule like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', "callback_image_upload['image',".$id."]");
```

and the function like this

```
function image_upload($param,$value,$id=''){


            if($_FILES[$value]['name'] == ''){
                $this->form_validation->set_message('image_upload', 
                              'The %s field can not be Null');
                return false;       
            }else{
                return true;
            }

    }
```

while submitting the form I got error like this
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: 'image',

please any body help me if possible

Comment: Please check your form file image field name and pass it into first parameter of set_rules. here you have passed 'image' but in your form its different please check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form selector is correct like..

**Html >>**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type='file' name='userfile' required>
```

**At controller validation**

```
if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
 {   
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'callback_file_selected_test');
  }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
         //error
     }
    else{
           // success       
      }

function file_selected_test(){

    $this->form_validation->set_message('file_selected_test', 'Please select file.');
    if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

You may check this code every where in stackoverflow.  If any other issue please comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the inconvenience. I think that was my mistake and realize that code igniter call back function takes only one parameter. I have re written the code like this and working it perfectly.

```
$parameters = 'image' . ',' . $id;
$this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', 'callback_validate_image['.$parameters.']');

    function validate_image($param,$x){

            list($value, $id) = explode(',', $x);

            if($id){
                $hdn = "h_".$value;
                if($this->input->post($hdn) == ''){

                    if(empty($_FILES[$value]['name'])){
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'The %s field  is required.');
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        return true;
                    }
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }else{
                if($_FILES[$value]['name'] == ''){
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_image', 'The %s field  is required.');
                    return false;       
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Its all written in controller it self. please post your answers if possible to move the validate_image function to model if possible. thank you for the effort